# MySQL DataBase automatic reset after 1 hour for Demo Mode

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

I wish to create a demo mode for my CMS and is there anyway with which I can set my MySQL database automatically reset after 1 hour of time.

Comment: Strange requirement. Maybe a [Scheduled Event](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/) fits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the hosting console, you need a database running with the initial data set. Only once, you need to get a database dump in a file:

```
mysqldump -u DBUSER -pDBPASS --opt DBNAME > /path/to/my/backup.sql
```

Then, create a cron job (run `crontab -e`) to run a database restore using your dump file (see http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference for more information about cron tabs)

```
mysql -u DBUSER -pDBPASS DBNAME < /path/to/my/backup.sql
```

For example:

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * mysql -u root -p123456 demo < /path/to/my/demo_backup.sql
```

This will restore your database to the original state ***every hour*** (minute `00`)

*Note: You need to consider, also, that if some user is actually trying your demo and the database is running the reset process, the user data will be lost in the middle of the session.*